# Hyperterminal and alerts

Tags: alerts, hyperterminal

I have a device that sends data to Hyperterminal. What I want is that when a certain piece of text appears is to get an alert, either audible or visual. Is there any software/scripts etc available that might of that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be as well using vb .net or similar and listen to the device using the comms port directly. You can then trigger an event based on the returned data.

There's some useful info here:
[How to access serial and parallel ports by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823179)

Comment: I shall take a look at your link.. regards

Comment: It's quite easy to do, I've done the same thing several times using VB6 in the past. Good luck.